Operating on photo retrieved from php page using python
I want to make pseudo-verification api in python that works with images(ID of a worker). It is supposed to be based on certain patterns in image like(circles squares etc. like in snapchat famous system). How do i run python script whenever image is sent from user using normal html input file form? I mean like user sends photo to server, it runs script in python and gives verdict? Thanks in advance.
I tried looking up problem on the internet. I didn't find any solutions. It seems like it's really expensive operation and probably suboptimatl, but neverthelles I want to do it that way.

You can create that solution, using a combination of PHP+Python, there are several libraries that can operate images to get to a desired result, in case of employee ID verification, the python script should be capable of recognizing what is looking at, for this example let's there is a colleague in the company and a camera device or similar takes a picture of the ID:
Client side application will require constant read of the camera or a picture, here is the code for a camera and a local saved picture:
Python Bar code reader: (Involving Numpy is a good idea to enhance the cv2 bar code recognition)
##import cv2
##img = cv2.imread('/home/jbsidis/Pictures/sofiaID.png')
##
##barcode_detector = cv2.barcode_BarcodeDetector()
##
### 'retval' is boolean mentioning whether barcode has been detected or not
##retval, points, _ = barcode_detector.detectAndDecode(img)
##
### copy of original image
##img2 = img.copy()
##
### proceed further only if at least one barcode is detected:
##if retval:
##    points = points.astype(np.int)
##    for i, point in enumerate(points):
##        img2 = cv2.drawContours(img2,[point],0,(0, 255, 0),2)
##
##
##print(retval,points,barcode_detector.detectAndDecode(img))

import sys
import cv2
import time
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if (camera.isOpened() == False):
    print("Can not open camera #0.")
    sys.exit(0)
print("Camera ready")
doAgain = True
while doAgain:
    ret, image = camera.read()
    if ret:
        qrCodeDetector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
        text, points, _ = qrCodeDetector.detectAndDecode(image)
        if points is not None:
            print(text)
            cv2.imwrite("./result.jpg",image)
        else:
            print("QR code not detected")
        cv2.imshow("Image", image)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == 27:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            doAgain = False
camera.release()

Server side application (PHP):
<?php
//server side for the python process
$target_dir = "uploads/"; //add a directory where to save the file in the server
//this receives the data from the HTML form
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $file = $_FILES["picture"];
    if ($file["type"] != "image/jpeg" && $file["type"] != "image/png" && $file["type"] != "image/gif") {
        echo "This file is not allowed! IMages only please";
        exit();
    }
    if ($file["size"] > 1000000) {
        echo "Error: File size is too large.";
        exit();
    }
    // here we are guessing that you have storage in your server or php server
    $filename = basename($file["name"]);
    $target_path = $target_dir . $filename;
    move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $target_path);

    echo "THanks for uploading the image, Barcode is being recognized!";
} else {
    echo "No file was uploaded. Try again please";
}
if (move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $target_path)) {
    // this will run the script the python script we created, you have to modify to if this will read the png or the image file or a camera, in this case it must be the camera 
    $python_script = "python /securepathtothescriptorsomeonecouldfindit/to/your/python/script.py " . $target_path;
    $output = shell_exec($python_script);
    echo "Barcode generated successfully!";
} else {
    echo "There was an error processing your image, please contact support";
}
?>

Client side (The user who is visiting your website or webapp):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>User will upload Picture</title>
    <style>
        .card {width: 900px;background-color: #f9f9f9;border: 1px solid #ddd;border-radius: 10px;box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);padding: 20px;margin: 40px auto;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card">
        <h2>Upload Picture</h2>
        <form action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="picture" accept="image/*">
            <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>
        <div id="image-preview"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        
        const fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

        
        fileInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (event) => {
                const imageDataUrl = event.target.result;

                
                document.getElementById('image-preview').innerHTML = `<img src="${imageDataUrl}" alt="Uploaded Image width=200 height=550">`;
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Result:

To test this, you can install XAMPP or a similar tool to locally run a PHP server and test it offline without cloud or you can use a public hosting compatible with PHP and test it.

You could try by setting up a web server using Flask. By using it, you can next handle the file uploads from the HTML form, so, when an image is uploaded you can process it using a Python script to detect patterns like circles and squares.
Finally, you should send the result back to the user.
To resume:

Set up Flask
Create the Flask application with python (there are a lot of good tutorials out there)
Create the HTML form
Run the Flask Application
Access the Web Application

Hope this helps.

Would it work if I'm sending photo from .php file? And if yes how would I go about it?

Yes, it would work. You should follow the same steps. Install Flask, create the Flask App using python and next, create a PHP script to send the photo to the Flask server, by creating first the php form (let's call it upload.html, and then creating the php script (upload.php) . To run it, start the Flask server, open the PHP form and select an image to upload.
